# Foursquare venues as areas, not points

Tags: foursquare, geo

Venues in the Foursquare API seem to be simple coordinates. This means that all photos taken in a large venue like a university building can be collapsed down, and appear as if they were all taken at a single point.

Is there any way to figure out how large the Foursquare venue really is, so I know that a huge spike of photos at a specific point is really gathered from a larger area?

Foursquare doesn't seem to track such information, but perhaps someone else has mapped venues  to buildings or bounding boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually fields in a [venue details](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) response that can give you a sense of a venue's size. Within the `location` object, we expose the `radius50` and `radius90` whose values are the radius from the center of the venue needed to encompass 50% and 90% of the check-ins at venue, respectably. For example, if `radius50` had a value of `35`, this means that half the check-ins to this place took place within the region 35m out from the venue's reported lat/lon.

While not a perfect measurement of size or a bounding box, this can definitely give you some insights. For example, comparing the `radius50` and `radius90` values for a [restaurant](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3) and [airport](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/43a52546f964a520532c1fe3) indicates that the airport is significantly larger than the restaurant.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that.

Comment: Has this been discontinued? I don't see any mention of it.

Comment: @dukedave: nope, still looks like it's still there: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3

Comment: @octopi are you sure? [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/iHuN01K.png) what I see in the `location` object for the venue at the URL you linked, no sign of any `radiusNN` keys.

Comment: @octopi Seems to be gone for me as well. :( Any hope of getting this information in some other way?

Comment: Hey guys, it actually looks like I had spoken too soon previously. This data seemed to have always been locked down to special Foursquare accounts (SU's, admins, etc.). If you think your app has an exceptional case for using this data, you can always get in touch with us: api@foursquare.com